# Plot multiple rectangles

Tags: r

I am a real dummy in R. Could you please explain me how to plot multiple rectangles as in example plot below, by using `rect`?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/rect.html


This link should help a bit, it has a nice example with the coloring and shading example.

Comment: Yes, but my problem is another. One rect is fine, but how to produce multiple?

Comment: Did you look at the coloring and shading example? It plots 4 of them there using a coordinate grid. Isn't that what you are asking for?

Comment: I have looked. But is there a way to do automatically, without specifying every time new rectangular?

Comment: Oh, I see, I am sorry for the confusion. Looks like a person has answered it nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
plot(c(0, 100), c(0, 100), type = "n", axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "")
rect(10, 10, 90, seq(10, 90, 1), border = "lightgray", lwd = 3)
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much! That what i was looking for!

Comment: Sorry for more disturbing. Is it possible to connect `rect` coordinates with `par` of existing figure?